# How to Set Enviornmental Variables that have - (dash) options

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to build a piece of software on linux and I need to set up the following environmental variables in a bash shell.

BLAS_LIBRARIES=-L/home/someuser/GotoBLAS2/lib -lgoto2 -lgfortran -lpthread
CUBLAS_LIBRARIES=-L/usr/local/cuda/4.0.17/cuda/lib64 -lcublas -lcudart -lcuda

When I do this in the bash shell I get the errors:
bash: -lgoto2: command not found
bash: -lcublas: command not found

Can anyone tell me how to set these up without getting these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to quote them:

```
BLAS_LIBRARIES="-L/home/someuser/GotoBLAS2/lib -lgoto2 -lgfortran -lpthread "
```

Comment: Also note that the problem with not quoting it is due to the spaces, not the - characters.